# Detect when loading AMP environment from javascript within an <amp-iframe>

Tags: javascript, iframe, amp-html, detect

I have a javascript file that is deployed across different websites and I would like to be able to detect from the javascript, those instances which are loading within the AMP environment.

If I wasn't within an iframe, I would be able to check using the `window.AMP` property, but unfortunately, this seems to be unavailable within an amp-iframe and I cannot access the parent due to cross-domain policy. Does anyone know of another way to detect the AMP environment here?

Comment: I have the same question... seems surprisingly difficult to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like inside iframe of amp components we can use:

```
window.ampSeen
```

I can't find any official information about this method, but it seems you should using 3p rendering: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aampproject+ampSeen&type=code

---

Another way is checking some amp global properties like:

```
window.context.data.ampSlotIndex
```